# Allow utorrent download on college LAN

Tags: networking, proxy, vpn, utorrent

I have my college LAN connected to my notebook. It is proxied already, i.e. the LAN works only if we are connected to that proxy network...!
I want to use utorrent and download from it, but it does not connect to peers at all...!
What should I do...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mobile hotspot from your phone just long enough for it to connect to at least one peer then switch back to your college wifi. If your college wifi is like mine then they are using a blocker that blocks bittorrent clients however I've found it only stops them from starting it won't stop them if you're already downloading.